Optimizing PostgreSQL Searches with Multiple Range Filters Over Different Columns
I'm working on optimizing PostgreSQL queries for a database where I need to filter results based on multiple range conditions across different columns. Specifically, I have a table named transactions, and I need to perform searches where I filter records based on the posted_at timestamp column and the amount numeric column simultaneously.
SELECT * 
FROM transactions 
WHERE posted_at > '2024-01-01' AND posted_at < '2024-03-01' 
  AND amount > 1000 AND amount < 5000;

My more specific questions:

What indexing strategies are recommended for optimizing searches over timestamp (posted_at) and numeric (amount) columns concurrently?
How does the order of columns in a multi-column index affect query performance in this context? Both amount and posted_at have a wide range of values.
Are there Postgres configuration settings tailored to improving performance for range queries over multiple columns?

I tried creating a B-tree index on both the posted_at timestamp and the amount columns at the same time. I also tried making separate B-tree indexes for each column. This time, PostgreSQL used a bitmap AND index scan. It was better, but I'm still not satisfied with the performance. I'm wondering if I can do better here.

Please share the complete DDL for all tables and indexes involved. And the query plan using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings). All in plain text, as an update of your question.

In the example you post, the ranges are quite ample. If the predicates are not good at filtering data out, then the query will end up selecting a significant percentage of the table. Is that true in your case?

A multicolumn gist index can efficiently support range conditions on multiple columns at the same time.  You would need the btree_gist extension to build such an index on those column types.
The problem is that gist indexes are slower to build and maintain, and also have a higher overhead to use.  At some point the greater efficiency might overcome the greater overhead, but where that will happen is hard to predict.  You should try it and see.
But the BitmapAnd on the btree indexes might be hard to beat.  You could try to optimize that (like by increasing work_mem if it goes lossy, or increasing effecitve_io_concurrency, or by increasing parallelization) but without the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) we are flying blind.
